# Add Enterprise Keywords with the SharePoint REST API v1

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, enterprise-keywords, file-metadata

I am working with the SharePoint REST API v1 with Js. I have a fetch that retrieves all the items inside the Documents list and it returns me a JSON with all the data. I am interested in the "TaxKeyword" part, as I want to have the ability of creating or modifying existing Labels (Enterprise Keywords ) with new ones.

This is an example of a file that has an existing Label:

```
"TaxKeyword": {
                    "__metadata": {
                        "type": "Collection(SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue)"
                    },
                    "results": [
                        {
                            "Label": "Malta",
                            "TermGuid": "I am not sure if I can share this so I prefer not to",
                            "WssId": 7
                        }
                    ]
                },
```

It is possible to change this value to another? And If the file doesn't have an Enterprise Keywords , how I can do to assign a new Label? (Because I suppose I should generate a new TermGuid)

I am not sure If I've explained correctly, sorry in advance and thank you.

-----------------------EDIT----------------------------------------

I found a solution for updating a current label, still don't know how to create a new label from scratch.

Basically, for updating a label you need to make a POST with the next url:

_api/Web/lists/getByTitle('TaxonomyHiddenList')/items(7)

The number inside items is the "WssID" value. You need to update all the following values with the new label that you want.

```
{
    "__metadata": {
        "type": "SP.Data.TaxonomyHiddenListListItem"
    },
"Title": "Malta2",
"Term": "Malta2",
"Path": "Malta2",
"CatchAllDataLabel": "Malta2#Љ|",
"Term1031": "Malta2",
"Path1031": "Malta2",
"Term1036": "Malta2",
"Path1036": "Malta2",
"Term2108": "Malta2",
"Path2108": "Malta2",
"Term1057": "Malta2",
"Path1057": "Malta2",
"Term1044": "Malta2",
"Path1044": "Malta2",
"Term1049": "Malta2",
"Path1049": "Malta2",
"Term2052": "Malta2",
"Path2052": "Malta2",
"Term1028": "Malta2",
"Path1028": "Malta2",
"Term1081": "Malta2",
"Path1081": "Malta2",
"Term1086": "Malta2",
"Path1086": "Malta2",
"Term1060": "Malta2",
"Path1060": "Malta2",
"Term1030": "Malta2",
"Path1030": "Malta2",
"Term1069": "Malta2",
"Path1069": "Malta2",
"Term1035": "Malta2",
"Path1035": "Malta2",
"Term1043": "Malta2",
"Path1043": "Malta2",
"Term1051": "Malta2",
"Path1051": "Malta2",
"Term1068": "Malta2",
"Path1068": "Malta2",
"Term1026": "Malta2",
"Path1026": "Malta2",
"Term1110": "Malta2",
"Path1110": "Malta2",
"Term1055": "Malta2",
"Path1055": "Malta2",
"Term1106": "Malta2",
"Path1106": "Malta2",
"Term1050": "Malta2",
"Path1050": "Malta2",
"Term1038": "Malta2",
"Path1038": "Malta2",
"Term1042": "Malta2",
"Path1042": "Malta2",
"Term1063": "Malta2",
"Path1063": "Malta2",
"Term1071": "Malta2",
"Path1071": "Malta2",
"Term1033": "Malta2",
"Path1033": "Malta2",
"Term1025": "Malta2",
"Path1025": "Malta2",
"Term1041": "Malta2",
"Path1041": "Malta2",
"Term1062": "Malta2",
"Path1062": "Malta2",
"Term1164": "Malta2",
"Path1164": "Malta2",
"Term1046": "Malta2",
"Path1046": "Malta2",
"Term2070": "Malta2",
"Path2070": "Malta2",
"Term9242": "Malta2",
"Path9242": "Malta2",
"Term1054": "Malta2",
"Path1054": "Malta2",
"Term5146": "Malta2",
"Path5146": "Malta2",
"Term1029": "Malta2",
"Path1029": "Malta2",
"Term3082": "Malta2",
"Path3082": "Malta2",
"Term1037": "Malta2",
"Path1037": "Malta2",
"Term1045": "Malta2",
"Path1045": "Malta2",
"Term10266": "Malta2",
"Path10266": "Malta2",
"Term2074": "Malta2",
"Path2074": "Malta2",
"Term1058": "Malta2",
"Path1058": "Malta2",
"Term1032": "Malta2",
"Path1032": "Malta2",
"Term1061": "Malta2",
"Path1061": "Malta2",
"Term1040": "Malta2",
"Path1040": "Malta2",
"Term1087": "Malta2",
"Path1087": "Malta2",
"Term1053": "Malta2",
"Path1053": "Malta2",
"Term1066": "Malta2",
"Path1066": "Malta2",
"Term1027": "Malta2",
"Path1027": "Malta2",
"Term1048": "Malta2",
"Path1048": "Malta2"
}
```

In postman, apart from the autogenerated Headers I use this ones:

```
Accept:application/json;odata=verbose
X-HTTP-Method:MERGE
Content-Type:application/json;odata=verbose
If-Match:*
X-RequestDigest:{form_digest_value}
```

I still don't know how to add a Label to a file that doesn't have labels at all, because if a file doesn't have that value, it will not appear on the TaxonomyHiddenList. I will keep searching.

I hope this will be usefull to someone that, like me, is doing the imposible for working with the SharePoint REST API and not using other technologies.